# facebook api params to get number of reactions

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I try to get the number of comments and shares from facebook api

this is what I did

```
$data = $this->request('GET', '/'.$this->page.'/posts?fields=type,shares,comments.limit(0).summary(true)&since=1474927200');

  [0]=>
  array(4) {
    ["type"]=>
    string(4) "link"
    ["shares"]=>
    array(1) {
      ["count"]=>
      int(81)
    }
    ["id"]=>
    string(30) "XXXX"
    ["comments"]=>
    array(0) {
    }
  }
```

It return the good number for the share but it gives me 0 for comments  , when I copy / paste in the graph explorer , the graph gives me the good result

From graph api :

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "type": "link",
      "shares": {
        "count": 81
      },
      "id": "XXXXXX",
      "comments": {
        "data": [
        ],
        "summary": {
          "order": "ranked",
          "total_count": 29,
          "can_comment": true
        }
      }
    },
```

Edit :

I just try an other thing

```
$response = $this->facebook->get('/XXXXX/posts?fields=comments.limit(0).summary(true),reactions.limit(0).summary(true)&limit=30');
$getPostID = $response->getGraphEdge()->asArray();
```

Without ->asArray(); It return the good result but I can't parse the node 
but With ->asArray(); It return 0

It is so weird ..

Comment: You didn't use the same access token I assume

Comment: I just try with the same access token and the result is the same :(

Comment: Then you are most likely making requests against different API versions. Specify the API version explicitly, if you have not done so yet.

Comment: even with the same version (I am using v2.7) the result is the same

Comment: I usually use `summary(1)` instead of `summary(true)`, but I doubt that makes a difference. (You are using the PHP SDK v5 here, right?)

Comment: yes I am using v5.0.0

Comment: I just add some more info

Comment: Ok , i found a solution , I need to use this $response->getDecodedBody(); instead of $response->getGraphEdge()->asArray();